# How would I set a boundary around an isometric grid?

Tags: swift, xcode, boundary, isometric

So I've made an isometric grid that would be the world/level of a game, and I want to set boundaries around the grid so the player can't go off of them. Since it's all slanted, and the functions I wrote to make the grids automatically place the tiles down, I can't trial and error CGPoints until I get them right. Here's the code that I used for the grid

```
func newTile(size:CGSize) -> SKShapeNode {
            let shape = SKShapeNode()
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:size.height / 2.0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:size.width / 2.0, y:0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:-size.height / 2.0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:-size.width / 2.0, y:0))
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.lineWidth = 1.0
            shape.fillColor = SKColor.gray
            return shape
        }



        func tilePosition(col:Int, row:Int) -> CGPoint {
            let x = (CGFloat(row) * tileWidth  / 2.0) + (CGFloat(col) * tileWidth  / 2.0)
            let y = (CGFloat(col) * tileHeight / 2.0) - (CGFloat(row) * tileHeight / 2.0)
            return CGPoint(x: x-2000, y: y-100)
        }

        let tileHeight:CGFloat = 45.0
        let tileWidth:CGFloat = 90.0
        let numRows = 40
        let numCols = 40
        let size = CGSize(width: tileWidth, height: tileHeight)

        for row in 1...numRows {
            for col in 1...numCols {
                let tile = newTile(size: size)
                tile.position = tilePosition(col: col, row: row)
                self.addChild(tile)
            }
        }
```

How would I set a boundary on the last tile that it creates?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas... -

Try to think in terms of player and grid, then we assign the boundary by collision (intersection) where the player and outside the grid. Eg outside grid.x < player.x. The grid is slanted so you can get the last "line" of the grid and get the intersection of the player and grid boundary lines to see if the player goes out of the boundary. Assign the boundary to the grid doesn't make sense to me (you can but it'll be not efficiently and odd) unless I read it wrong.  The collisions should be happening in the main loop in game.

OR

it seems you have grid n x m so you can try to see if you can assign the player in grid[][], otherwise it shouldn't be able to walk off (if it is turn based...)